# How do I search an XML tree with two different criteria using python?

Tags: python, lxml

I am stuck with this problem for the past few hours.

This is how the XML looks like

```
    <xmlblock>
        <data1>
              <username>someusername</username>
              <id>12345</id>
        </data1>
        <data2>
             <username>username</username>
             <id>11111</id>
        </data1>
    </xmlblock>
```

The problem is this:

I need the username when it matches a given id.

I am not sure how to do a double search using iterfind or any other lxml module in python.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

A (probably not the best) solution

```
>>> id_to_match = 12345
>>> for event, element in cElementTree.iterparse('xmlfile.xml'):
...     if 'data' in element.tag:
...        for data in element:
...            if data.tag == 'username':
...                username = data.text
...            if data.tag == 'id':
...                if data.text == id_to_match:
...                    print username
someusername
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, This code helps. However I find that the XML files don't have this <data> tag a consistent. Not sure how to find the parent level item dynamically.

Comment: is the username and id tag consistent? Then I can update my answer with something that will work without the data.

Comment: hi, Actually they are not consistent. In certain XMLs username could be in the reverse. So with this query it errors out.

Comment: reversed how? that you first have the id and then the username?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) the following should work

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parseString('<xmlblock><data1><username>someusername</username><id>12345</id></data1><data2><username>username</username><id>11111</id></data2></xmlblock>')
username = [elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('username') for elem in doc.getElementsByTagName('id') if elem.firstChild.data == '12345'][0][0].firstChild.data
print username
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

---

```
>>> xml = '''
    <xmlblock>
        <data1>
              <username>someusername</username>
              <id>12345</id>
        </data1>
        <data2>
             <username>username</username>
             <id>11111</id>
        </data2>
    </xmlblock>'''
>>> doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> matching_nodes = doc.xpath('//id[text()="11111"]/../username')
>>> for node in matching_nodes:
        print node.text
username
```